# Click a block on a table SELENIUM PYTHON

Tags: python, html, selenium, xpath, css-selectors

I am trying to click an empty block on a table. Here is the HTML code

```
<table class= "data_table" cellspacing="0">
 <tbody>
  <tr>
   <td class="matrix_cell" sytle= "width:32"></td>
   <td class="matrix_cell" sytle= "width:32"></td>
   <td class="matrix_cell" sytle= "width:32"></td>
   <td class="matrix_cell" sytle= "width:32"></td>
   <td class="matrix_cell" sytle= "width:32"></td>
   <td class="matrix_cell" sytle= "width:32"></td> #the cell I want to click
   <td class="matrix_cell" sytle= "width:32"></td>
```

the xpath of this cell is

```
cellclick=driver.find_element_by_xpath("id('timeline_data')/table/tbody/tr[4]/td[2]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]").click()
```

The problem with the xpath is that cell may not always be empty.

I tried to loop through the table:

```
 cells=driver.find_element_by_class_name("data_table")
        for block in cells:
            if block ==6:
                block.click
```

I also tried using css_selector:

```
cells=driver.find_element_by_css_selector("td.matrix_cell:last-child").click()
```

**How can I click an empty cell (aka the 6th cell) on the table using selenium?**

Comment: Why is the xpath a problem if the cell isn't empty?  What happens?

Comment: I want to click on an empty cell. Not a cell that contains information.

Comment: So if the sixth cell contains information, what do you want to do?  Click on a different cell, or not click any cell at all?

Comment: Are you getting any errors? What do you expect to see?

Comment: If the 6th contains information I want to click on the next empty cell @JohnGordon

Comment: I expect for it to click on an empty cell. I believe looping seems logical @alecxe

Comment: What is currently happening? Any errors?

Answer (score 0):

Try below xpath :-

```
//*[@id='timeline_data']//table[@class='data_table']//td[6]
```

OR

```
//table[@class='data_table']//td[6]
```

Answer (score -1):

Why not use variables in your xpath? Every cell should have a number which differentiates it from others.
For example:

```
"/table/tbody/tr[4]/td["+ str(x) + "]/div/table/tbody/tr/td[6]"
```

You can equate `x = 1` and make a while loop to check the cell to be empty and if not empty make `x = x + 1` and so on. Hence when the cell is going to be empty, the row will be given by `x` and you can define you `xpath.click()` as the above example, but not with the correct variable/row.

This worked for me.